# PgSql jsonb_set for all occurance in json array

Tags: postgresql, json

I have a json like below

```
[
    {
        "rows": [
            {
                "col_class": "col50",
                "col_sec_id": 1626361165906,
                "col_sec_json": null
            },
            {
                "col_class": "col50",
                "col_sec_id": 1626361165907,
                "col_sec_json": {
                    "id": 1626361165907,
                    "data": {
                        "class": "0",
                         "location": "0",
                        "unitForCurrent": ""
                    },
                    "theme": "defaultTheme",
                    "layout": {
                        "fontSize": 14,
                        "fontStyle": "Open Sans",
                        "textColor": "#545454",
                        "isHeadingAlignmentInherited": true
                    },
                    "org_id": 1,
                    "to_date": "2020-12-31",
                    "interval": "Yearly"
                  }
            }
                   
        ],
        "col_sec_id": 1626360791978,
        "row_cols_count": 2
    },
 {
        "rows": [
            {
                "col_class": "col50",
                "col_sec_id": 1626361165906,
                "col_sec_json": null
            },
            {
                "col_class": "col50",
                "col_sec_id": 1626361165907,
                "col_sec_json": {
                    "id": 1626361165907,
                    "data": {
                        "class": "0",
                         "location": "0",
                        "unitForCurrent": ""
                    },
                    "theme": "defaultTheme",
                    "layout": {
                        "fontSize": 14,
                        "fontStyle": "Open Sans",
                        "textColor": "#545454",
                        "isHeadingAlignmentInherited": true
                    },
                    "org_id": 1,
                    "to_date": "2020-12-31",
                    "interval": "Yearly"
                  }
            }
                   
        ],
        "col_sec_id": 1626360791978,
        "row_cols_count": 2
    }

]
```

I want to update all ocurance of class inside rows->>cols->>col_sec_json->>data->>class to new value

I can update any specific item like below

```
select  jsonb_set(jdata, '{0,rows,1,col_sec_json,data,class}', '"new_value"')
```

But in above query I need to be like

```
select  jsonb_set(jdata, '{**---dyanamic for all rows ---** ,rows,**--- dynaic all colssec-json in each element of a rows---**,col_sec_json,data,class}', '"new_value"')
```

I tried alot but could not find,

Any help, highly appreciable...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to deconstruct the JSON, modify each array element, then rebuild the array

```
SELECT
    (SELECT jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_set(j1.value, '{rows}',
            (
             SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(j2.value, '{col_sec_json,data,class}', '"new_value"'))
             FROM jsonb_array_elements(j1.value->'rows') j2
            )
        ))
     FROM jsonb_array_elements(t.jdata) j1
     )
FROM YourTable t
```

Or as an `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE YourTable t
SET jdata = 
    (SELECT jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_set(j1.value, '{rows}',
            (
             SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(j2.value, '{col_sec_json,data,class}', '"new_value"'))
             FROM jsonb_array_elements(j1.value->'rows') j2
            )
        ))
     FROM jsonb_array_elements(t.jdata) j1
     )
;
```

`jsonb_array_elements` is used to deconstruct a JSON array into separate rows of JSON objects. Then `jsonb_set` modifies the object, and `jsonb_agg` aggregates it back into an array.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like charm.. now I need to understand this

Comment: Have added a bit of explanation

Comment: Thanks I got that from documents, trying to understand the order how this j1.value and j2 value working

Comment: can you help me how to update any key of say col_sec_json.to_date to some date

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I need to update values of multiple keys like update values of "rows->>cols->>col_sec_json->>data->>class" and rows->>cols->>col_sec_json->>to_date and "rows->>cols->>col_sec_json->>layout->>fontSize"

Comment: I'd advise you to rebuild the whole `col_sec_json` in that case, but that is a separate question and hould be in a new post

Comment: I am trying alot but not able to get... can you please help,  I have posted a new question..   https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/298318/pgsql-jsonb-set-for-all-occurance-of-multiple-keys-in-json-array