# PgSql jsonb_set for all occurance of multiple keys in json array

Tags: postgresql

I have below json

```
[
    {
        "rows": [
            {
                "col_class": "col50",
                "col_sec_id": 1626361165906,
                "col_sec_json": null
            },
            {
                "col_class": "col50",
                "col_sec_id": 1626361165907,
                "col_sec_json": {
                    "id": 1626361165907,
                    "data": {
                        "class": "0",
                         "location": "0",
                        "unitForCurrent": ""
                    },
                    "theme": "defaultTheme",
                    "layout": {
                        "fontSize": 14,
                        "fontStyle": "Open Sans",
                        "textColor": "#545454",
                        "isHeadingAlignmentInherited": true
                    },
                    "org_id": 1,
                    "to_date": "2020-12-31",
                    "interval": "Yearly"
                  }
            }
                   
        ],
        "col_sec_id": 1626360791978,
        "row_cols_count": 2
    },
 {
        "rows": [
            {
                "col_class": "col50",
                "col_sec_id": 1626361165906,
                "col_sec_json": null
            },
            {
                "col_class": "col50",
                "col_sec_id": 1626361165907,
                "col_sec_json": {
                    "id": 1626361165907,
                    "data": {
                        "class": "0",
                         "location": "0",
                        "unitForCurrent": ""
                    },
                    "theme": "defaultTheme",
                    "layout": {
                        "fontSize": 14,
                        "fontStyle": "Open Sans",
                        "textColor": "#545454",
                        "isHeadingAlignmentInherited": true
                    },
                    "org_id": 1,
                    "to_date": "2020-12-31",
                    "interval": "Yearly"
                  }
            }
                   
        ],
        "col_sec_id": 1626360791978,
        "row_cols_count": 2
    }

]
```

can update occurrence of a key like below

```
UPDATE YourTable t
SET jdata = 
    (SELECT jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_set(j1.value, '{rows}',
            (
             SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(j2.value, '{col_sec_json,data,class}', '"new_value"'))
             FROM jsonb_array_elements(j1.value->'rows') j2
            )
        ))
     FROM jsonb_array_elements(t.jdata) j1
     )
;
```

But trying to update multiple keys like

```
"rows->>cols->>col_sec_json->>data->>class"

"rows->>cols->>col_sec_json->>to_date" 

"rows->>cols->>col_sec_json->>layout->>fontSize"
```

How can I update above to achieve this..

output should be like

```
[
    {
        "rows": [
            {
                "col_class": "col50",
                "col_sec_id": 1626361165906,
                "col_sec_json": null
            },
            {
                "col_class": "col50",
                "col_sec_id": 1626361165907,
                "col_sec_json": {
                    "id": 1626361165907,
                    "data": {
                        "class": "new val",
                         "location": "0",
                        "unitForCurrent": ""
                    },
                    "theme": "defaultTheme",
                    "layout": {
                        "fontSize": 19,
                        "fontStyle": "Open Sans",
                        "textColor": "#545454",
                        "isHeadingAlignmentInherited": true
                    },
                    "org_id": 1,
                    "to_date": "2022-12-31",
                    "interval": "Yearly"
                  }
            }
                   
        ],
        "col_sec_id": 1626360791978,
        "row_cols_count": 2
    },
 {
        "rows": [
            {
                "col_class": "col50",
                "col_sec_id": 1626361165906,
                "col_sec_json": null
            },
            {
                "col_class": "col50",
                "col_sec_id": 1626361165907,
                "col_sec_json": {
                    "id": 1626361165907,
                    "data": {
                        "class": "new val",
                         "location": "0",
                        "unitForCurrent": ""
                    },
                    "theme": "defaultTheme",
                    "layout": {
                        "fontSize": 19,
                        "fontStyle": "Open Sans",
                        "textColor": "#545454",
                        "isHeadingAlignmentInherited": true
                    },
                    "org_id": 1,
                    "to_date": "2022-12-31",
                    "interval": "Yearly"
                  }
            }
                   
        ],
        "col_sec_id": 1626360791978,
        "row_cols_count": 2
    }

]
```

**Update**

I am able to do this using nested jsonb_set like below

```
(SELECT jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_set(j1.value, '{rows}',
            (
             SELECT jsonb_agg(
                 jsonb_set(
                 jsonb_set(j2.value, '{col_sec_json,data,class}', '"new_value"'),
                  '{col_sec_json,to_date}', '"some_data"')
             FROM jsonb_array_elements(j1.value->'rows') j2
            )
        ))
     FROM jsonb_array_elements(t.jdata) j1
     )
```

But I have doubt regarding the performance, I have seen some places that It can be done using || string concatenation operator, but when I tried, it was replacing original json object with new object with the keys that I replace.

Comment: What exactly do you want to update them with?

Comment: any dummy value

Comment: let's say class with "new val" ,, to_date wth "2022-12-31" and fontSize like 19

Answer (score 0):

Provided your json is stored in table t_jsonb2 column j:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_jspl(jsonb)
RETURNS jsonb
TRANSFORM FOR TYPE jsonb
LANGUAGE plperl
AS $$
 my @arg = shift;
 $arg[0]->[0]->{rows}->[1]->{col_sec_json}->{data}->{class} = 'newval';
 $arg[0]->[0]->{rows}->[1]->{col_sec_json}->{to_date} = '2022-12-31';
 $arg[0]->[0]->{rows}->[1]->{col_sec_json}->{layout}->{fontSize} = 19;

 # to update all
 for my $r (@arg[0]) {
   for my $s (@$r) {
     $s->{rows}->[1]->{col_sec_json}->{data}->{class} = 'newval2';
     $s->{rows}->[1]->{col_sec_json}->{to_date} = '2023-01-01';
     $s->{rows}->[1]->{col_sec_json}->{layout}->{fontSize} = 18;
   }
 }


 return $arg[0];
$$ ;


update t_jsonb2 t set j =  f_jspl(t.j);
```